# Using C# .NET DLL in C++Builder?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, c++builder

How can I use a C# .NET DLL in C++Builder?
I would like to use the functions of the C# dll's classes in C++Builder.

Answer (score 4):

In order to call managed code from unmanaged code under Windows, you pretty much have to go through COM.

In your case, this means building your C# library as *COM Visible* and registering it for COM Interoperation.

Then you need to invoke your COM object from the C++ code in the normal way.

There's a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7092618/2609288) which goes through the steps necessary to achieve this.