# Excel <-> C# - how do I call into a C# library from Excel?

Tags: c#, vba, excel, office-interop

We have a couple of spreadsheets here that we populate with some data and do some formatting using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`.

Now that part is all good - it's something along the lines of what is done here: [Write to Excel example](http://www.clear-lines.com/blog/post/Write-data-to-an-Excel-worksheet-with-C-fast.aspx).

What I'd like to do is:

- Add a button inside the spreadsheet, bound to a macro.
- When the user clicks the button, the macro fires - we grab some parameters from the cells and pass those to the C# function. That code does all the heavy lifting, populates the spreadsheet as above, etc.

What I don't understand how to do is that second step - I can't see a way to actually pass parameters and call into C# directly.
As it stands now, I can call a C# console application and pass command line parameters into it... but that seems a bit wrong, I'd have thought there would be some better way - but I can't seem to find it!

Comment: What about asking [Google](http://www.google.com)?

Comment: Do you own the C# code? If so, I think the only way is to register your assembly for COM interop. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7092618/122195).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coopernick,

It looks like you need to develop an Excel add-in and move the VBA code on the add-in rails. See [Walkthrough: Creating Your First Application-Level Add-in for Excel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668205.aspx) to get started quickly. You may consider an Excel add-in as a regular .Net application where you can use any components and libraries.

You may find the [Excel Solutions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386107(v=vs.90).aspx) section in MSDN helpful.