# left alt or right alt sendkey value vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I'm working on the `VBScript`, I use this code the send a `Num Lock Key`.

```
set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "{NUMLOCK}"
```

The problem is I want to send a `Left ALT Key` but I don't know the `SendKeys value`.

I searched some documents, it only contains ALT key SendKeys value, I don't know if we have a left or right Sendkeys value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `SendKeys()` method in `WScript.Shell` does not differentiate between <kbd>ALT</kbd> and <kbd>ALT GR</kbd> as you have observed. This is probably due to how <kbd>ALT</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> are treating as "modifiers" to existing keystrokes (see [`SendKeys` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/8c6yea83(v=vs.84))).

Some options would be;

- You could [build a COM library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7092553/692942) that you then use in VBScript via `CreateObject()` to capture the keystrokes for you.
- Use an existing COM library. There may be a cost involved (licencing etc.).
- Use another scripting framework like [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/), which has extended support for keystroke detection - See [Left Alt vs Right Alt](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/20837-left-alt-vs-right-alt/)

Comment: The instruction is clear, thank you.